# Does acegi use a different session from Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have been writing a web application that will only create one session per user.  This has worked well so far.  However, I am running into a problem where if I have a user logout, Spring thinks that user is still logged on.  I am invalidating the session with acegi upon logout, but it seems as if Spring does not recognize that:

```
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
                success-handler-ref="logout"
                logout-url="/logout.html" />
```

So, my question is: does there exist a separate spring session that I must invalidate, and if this is the case, how should I go about doing so?

Thanks in advance.
MirroredFate

Comment: for debugging purposes you can add a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to log when a session ends (or do something else similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if Acegi and SpringMVC use the same session then the answer is yes, they do. You may want to manually invalidate the session in the controller that handles `/logout.html`.

**UPDATE**

As the OP mentioned the in the comment below, to invalidate the authentication object use:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I did some more research, and eventually found that while they have the same session, Spring has an authenticate token that does not get "invalidated" when acegi invalidates the session.  Thus, I had to add this line of code:
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);

to my logout function.  I will mark this answer as correct (It did answer my question, after all).  If you would like to add that line of code to your answer, it might help others in a similar situation.